# Exposing ports or hide them behind proxy

Tags: web-application, proxy, ports

Are there any security threats when ports are exposed publicly instead of hiding them via proxy? E.g. server application listens on port **8090**. We can call this application directly **hostname:8090** or use a proxy (apache/nginx/etc/) to make redirect `hostname -> hostname:8090`.

Does this solution increase the level of security?

Answer (score 1):

This mainly depends on how you are doing the proxy.  If you are simply using mod_rewrite in Apache or Nginx to redirect from 80 to 8090 ... then there is no security gained at all.  This is the equiv of putting a sticky note on the front door of your house saying "please use the door in the back".  Anyone can read the sticky, and even if there isn't a sticky anyone could case the house and find the back door to be open (aka port scan your host).

If you need to have a web service that is only accessible by certain people one of the best ways to do it is to instead host the service on `localhost` or 127.0.0.1 ... this means that the port will not be accessible outside the box.  Then, in order get to the service you ssh port forward:

`ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:8090 example.com -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

the above is how to achieve ssh port forwarding in Linux, however it is also available via tools like [puTTY](http://www.putty.org/).

Using a ssh tunnel to access your service increases the level of security by:

- encrypting the communication between client and server
- protecting service behind pubkey (or password) auth used by ssh
- no external port to be scanned

If you do not want to setup SSH tunnel another option is [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I have a web application with api which is called by mobile application. So setting ssh tunnel is rather not  an option. I know that by passing request through proxy I can block direct access to application (e.g. by checking certificate). But I am still not sure if it is really needed.

Comment: ah, in that case you need to be using HTTPS and create some type of an API key

Comment: ofc, the https and authorization is included. The only thing I wonder is if the port is exposed, is there a possible security threat. When I call https://hostname:PORT/ Header Authorization SUPER_SECURE_TOKEN is it less secure then through proxy https://hostname/ -> http://hostname:PORT

Comment: no, remapping the port will still not buy you any added security ... but an API key over HTTPS is pretty much industry standard.  It should be good enough for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: And I have them - authorisation, https... My question was ONLY about exposing ports. If I understand you, in your opinion exposing ports is not a security threat and  doesn't provide extra value comparing to hiding it over  subdomain name (myservice.domain.com -> redirect to 8090 vs domain.com:8090).

Comment: domain.com:8090 vs myservice.domain.com ... non standard ports will hide you from someone doing a nmap scan on only 80 & 443 ... however its similar to the back door analogy ... a car driving down the road might not see your back door open, but someone casing your building will.  Same is true of using a non-standard port

Comment: It is not this case (I don't want hide it by using non standard port). Assume we have a frontend application in js. And the backend with 2 microservices - app1:8090 and app2:8080. The question is if calling them via exposed ports is equally secure (I'm not talking about authorisation) to the situation when we hide them by using sobdomain and proxy redirect.

Comment: @kadiii: Yes, if by equally secure you mean that you don't introduce any more security holes than are already there in your microservices. But the point is that by hiding your microservices behind a proxy, you most likely *decrease* the attack surface on your microservices because there are  classes of attacks that get taken care of by the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly common pattern is to have a heavy-duty proxy such as apache or nginx that does all the http heavy lifting and takes care of https termination (e.g. handles SSL for you). Your application sits hidden behind that.

Such a setup has some advantages:

1. It makes your application server much simpler, because you don't have to worry about caching, SSL encryption and a ton of details that apache and nginx are good at handling. Note that if your application server does the SSL itself, a proxy sitting in front of it won't be able to cache anything, so from a performance point of view, it makes sense not to let the application server take care of SSL.
2. Letting apache/nginx handle client requests first will direct any attack at apache/nginx first, and they're well-tested and hardened against attacks, which probably isn't true for your application server.
3. Apache and nginx are probably more performant than your application server. So you can have them serve static content and at the same time have them deal with all the security implications of letting a server process access your server filesystem. Chances are that locking down apache and nginx is easier than making sure your application server doesn't have any security holes in it's code to serve static files (this is a specific example of point 2).

However, you only get these security benefits if you don't make your application server accessible to the public. So you either have to make it only listen on localhost, or have your firewall close the relevant ports.

This also means that using HTTP redirects to have apache/nginx redirect to your application server port won't work any more (and in fact it shouldn't, because using HTTP redirects won't help to hide your application server from the public internet at all). Instead, you'll have to configure apache/nginx to act as a proxy using their proxy directives.

Comment: But the question was only about exposing ports... Not about how to secure api or about use proxy or not. Could you give insights about it?

Comment: Your question is titled "exposing ports or hiding them behind proxy". How is this "not about use proxy or not"? My answer argues that it is better not to expose application ports directly and instead proxy them behind a real web server, which can enhance security.